# Insert new row to Database table if two fields does not match, otherwise sum value in certain column

Tags: c#, sql

I have data in Database table:

[image]

Here is the method for adding data:

```
    public static void AddRecordToDatatable(string WindowTitle, int TimeSpent,
        DateTime DateToday, string Project, string Username)
    {
        string sql = @"INSERT INTO dbo.Log (WindowTitle,TimeSpent,DateToday,Project,Username)" + 
                            " VALUES (@WindowTitle,@TimeSpent,@DateToday,@Project,@Username)";

        // Create the connection (and be sure to dispose it at the end)
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(DBconnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                // Open the connection to the database. 
                // This is the first critical step in the process.
                // If we cannot reach the db then we have connectivity problems
                cnn.Open();

                // Prepare the command to be executed on the db
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
                {
                    // Create and set the parameters values 
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@WindowTitle", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = WindowTitle;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TimeSpent", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TimeSpent;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateToday", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.Date;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Project", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Project;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Username;

                    // Let's ask the db to execute the query
                    int rowsAdded = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (rowsAdded > 0)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("Row inserted");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // This should never really happen, but let's leave it here
                        //MessageBox.Show("No row inserted");
                    }
                }
                cnn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // We should log the error somewhere, 
                // for this example let's just show a message
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

How it is possible to check for existing record before inputting data to Database table and sum on certain value if it exists?

So basically check if `WindowTitle = WindowTitle` and `DateToday = DateToday`, if these two match, then take TimeSpent and sum it to existing TimeSpent in Database Table without inputting a new row.

I have tried to test `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE WindowTitle = @WindowTitle, DateToday = @DateToday` after `INSERT` but Visual Studio is giving an error in Debugger for such a command pointing to ON (Incorrect syntax near ON). Also I am not sure if `ON DUPLICATE` is the best approach for this kind of case.

Comment: You need a Select method before doing the Insert.  If the UserName is a Primary Key than you need to use Update instead of Insert (except if it is a new account).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand your SQL to check for the existence of the record you think could exist.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Log WHERE WindowTitle = @WindowTitle AND DateToday = @DateToday)
BEGIN
    --UPDATE HERE
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   -- INSERT HERE
END
```

Alternatively you can create a query method and call that first, before calling `AddRecordToDatatable`

Personally I would do all of these CRUD operations using an ORM such as EF Core or preferably, NHibernate. But this all depends on requirements, limitations etc.